# Java very simple 'catch' without 'try' error

Tags: java

Two errors `catch` without `try`
`try` without `catch`, `finally` or resource declarations

```
    try {
        File file = new File("path to file");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String line;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in input/output");
        }
        scanner.close();
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not how a try/catch block works.

Comment: Your catch statement cannot be inside your try block.

Comment: you have a semi-colon issue.

Comment: It's `try {...} catch {...}`, not `try {... catch {...}}`.

Comment: Count your braces carefully.  Voting to close as your issue is down to a typo.

Answer (score 2):

The catch block must be ***outside*** of the try block, not inside:

```
 try {
        File file = new File("path to file");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        String line;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in input/output");
} finally {
        scanner.close();
}
```